# GPUImage with Swift, setcompletionblock

Tags: swift, gpuimage

I'm trying to use the GPUImage library in Swift, but I don't know how to translate this snippet of objective-c code to swift:

```
[movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    [filter removeTarget:movieWriter];
    [movieWriter finishRecording];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [timer invalidate];
        self.progressLabel.text = @"100%";
    });

    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathToMovie, nil, NULL, NULL);
}];
```

How do I call the setCompletionBlock method in Swift?

Comment: What have you tried?  [so] is not a translation service.  There are several lines of code here.  What parts are giving you what trouble?

Comment: I know, as I said I cannot call the method setcompletionblock for movieWriter. That's the problem. @nhgrif
I don't now if there is a another way to do it in swift or what.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tried it with a working example but blocks in Swift should be something like this:

```
movieWriter.setCompletionBlock({
    // …

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // …
    })
})
```